# Monoid but not a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, monoid

so I am studying in Germany and I stumbled upon this kind of question 
so I have this set given

$$M :=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\   
0 & b \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
       $a$ and $b$ are elements of the natural numbers

Now I have to show that $(M, ·)$ is a monoid but not a group. 
How should I do that?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a 2x2 matrix with entries $a,b$ on the diagonal?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it kept changing it to look like this

Answer (score 1):

For $a=1$ and $b=1$ we get an identity element $e$.

The associative property is obvious because we have it in $\mathbb N$.

Thus, it's indeed a monoid.

But for  $x\in M$ there is a problem with $y\in M$ for which $xy=e.$

For example, take $a=2$ and $b=1$.

Thus, it's not a group.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what is the difference between groups and monoids.

> Groups have inverses to all elements

And try to exploit that.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The Fact that will show it is Monoi not a Group is that 
" Inverse doesn't exist for all elements"

Let take  matrix 
[3 0 
 0 6] 
And there doesn't exist inverse for this

While all othe properties like 
Associativity
Closure
Identity - I 
are satisfied. 
Hope it helped u